# What does single threaded nature of Node mean

Tags: node.js

When we say Node is a single threaded application - does it mean that Node generates one single thread per request or is it single thread across all requests to be served. If it is single thread per request, then how can we limit the number of requests served in unit time? If it is single thread for all requests, then how are node services able to serve multiple users seemingly at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There's one thread, total. It's able to serve multiple clients by not blocking. When one client gives up the cpu to wait on something, it handles another client. It means you have to be careful writing node apps. Any code you have that is cpu intensive will hold up the entire server.